# Sub methods in Javascript classes

Tags: javascript, subclass

## The problem

I'd like to be able to use classes to create client objects and add address objects to an array within them.

### What I'd like to be able to do

```
let client = new Client ('A123', 'John', 'Smith', avatarUrl);
client.address('home').add(address);
```

## My current classes

### Working version

```
class Client extends Name {
  constructor(clientRef, firstName, lastName, profilePic) {
    super (firstName, lastName, profilePic);
    this._id = clientRef;
    this.addresses = [];
  }
  addAddress (address, label = 'main') {
    address = {...address, label}
    this.addresses.push(address);
  }
  removeAddress (label = 'main') {
    this.addresses = this.addresses.filter((element) => { return element.label != label; });
  }
}
```

### Non-working version

This is what I'm trying to create, but it doesn't work.

```
class Client extends Name {
  constructor(clientRef, firstName, lastName, profilePic) {
    super (firstName, lastName, profilePic);
    this._id = clientRef;
    this.addresses = [];
  }
  address (label = 'main') {
    add (address) {
      address = {...address, label}
      this.addresses.push(address);
    }
    remove () {
      this.addresses = this.addresses.filter((element) => { return element.label != label; });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using classes, consider extracting the whole of that `address` method into another class. I'd call it `AddressHolder` or `AddressManager`. At any rate, it's not very good design to have an entire *method* have methods of its own.

Comment: @VLAZ that's not necessarily bad design. One of the benefits of JavaScript is are closures, and to create an object holding functions without the need to define a class. If `this.addresses` should be represented as an own class depends heavily on what further features are required later on.

Comment: @t.niese My thinking is tied to the fact that there are classes. When working with classes, I like to enforce SRP. It makes it easier to reason about code, as well as maintain it. Were this more functional or free-form approach, I wouldn't see *as much* of a problem, but I'd still advocate for the address logic to be added separately as a mixin or composition. In all cases, addresses always deserve separate logic to handle them, so mixing the address handling with anything else that has addresses is likely to come back and bite you sooner or later.

Comment: @VLAZ `[...]My thinking is tied to the fact that there are classes. When working with classes, I like to enforce SRP.[...]` that does not mean that you have to use distinct classes for that, just because classes exist. You always should consider all language features an choose the appropriate one.  `[...]addresses always deserve separate logic to handle them, so mixing the address handling with anything[...]` that's my point in the current from the address array does not have much logic, so forcing a class on it is not necessarily the best decision.

Comment: It seems you try to develop what is known as a fluent API. There are diverse frameworks and articles to help you achieve this. Using plain home-grown code is also possible and not difficult but your approach is (as mentioned) indeed not the best path.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to assign values to a class method as if it were a key-value object store. It's a function that will return a null reference without a return statement. What you need to do it return a key-value store that has the methods you want, like this:

```js
class Client extends Name {
  constructor(clientRef, firstName, lastName, profilePic) {
    super (firstName, lastName, profilePic);
    this._id = clientRef;
    this.addresses = [];
  }
  address (label = 'main') {
    return {
      add: (address) => {
        address = {...address, label}
        this.addresses.push(address);
      },
      remove: () => {
        this.addresses = this.addresses.filter((element) => { return element.label != label; });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your help.  I'm going to try expanding my current Address class to include methods

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to return an object holding these functions, but you need to ensure that `this` points to the original Client object, and for that, you could utilize arrow functions:

```
class Client extends Name {
  constructor(clientRef, firstName, lastName, profilePic) {
    super(firstName, lastName, profilePic);
    this._id = clientRef;
    this.addresses = [];
  }
  address(label = 'main') {
    return {
      add: (address) => {
        address = {
          ...address,
          label
        }
        this.addresses.push(address);
      },
      return: () => {
        this.addresses = this.addresses.filter((element) => {
          return element.label != label;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could the one down-voting explain why.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your help.  I'm going to try expanding my current Address class to include methods

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to make it work:

```
address (label = 'main') {
  return {
    add: (address) => {
      this.addresses.push({...address, label});
    },
    remove: () => {
      this.addresses = this.addresses.filter((element) => { return element.label != label; });
    }
  }
}
```

But I recommend to move `address` to another class and return it as result.

```
class Address {

  constructor(label) {
    this.label = label;
  }

  add(address) {
    for (const name in address) {
      this[name] = address[name];
    }
  }
}

class Client {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.addresses = [];
  }

  address(label) {
    const address = new Address(label);

    this.addresses.push(address);

    return address;
  }
}


const client = new Client('John', 18);

client.address('home').add({
  str: 'Main',
  house: 55
})
```

Comment: You do not need `const self = this` alongside arrow functions.

Comment: Yep, my bad, fixed :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had already create `Address` as a class, but hadn't added methods to it.  I'll give this a try and report back.  As soon as I've tried it, I'll mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Adding works really well.  Thank you.  I couldn't see how to `remove` as I need to filter from the `clients.addresses` array, which isn't within the `Address` class.